# Reportico output only PDF or CSV

Tags: laravel, reportico

I am using Laravel extension of **Reportico 5.2.0** for report generation. 
I have a form in which I fill all the query parameters and have buttons to get output of HTML, PDF, CSV.

I am able to fetch the HTML output as it is written in a view and is returned via ajax.

I would like to get PDF when I click on PDF button.

I tried this documentation but was unsuccessful
http://www.reportico.org/swsite/site/doc/reportico/tutorial_reportico.using.pkg.html#using.embedding

When I try to embed link within view following their laravel documentation here http://www.reportico.org/laravel/public/index.php/embed-links
it states `ModeController Not found error`

Is it possible to get PDF only when clicked on the link or via ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

I just needed to point my url to

```
http://{laravel_app_url}/index.php/reportico/ajax?project={project-name}
&target_format=PDF&report={XML-file}
```

and change the `target_format` accordingly for the output type. But the caveat is, I need to generate the HTML output before generating the PDF and CSV output.

Answer (score 1):

Also another way to do it is use the dedicated route for running a report :-

`http://{laravel_app_url}/index.php/reportico/execute/{project-name}/{reportname-without-xml-extension}?target_format=PDF`

And to open a report in criteria entry mode

`http://{laravel_app_url}/index.php/reportico/prepare/{project-name}/{reportname-without-xml-extension}`

Comment: When I use the dedicated route I get `NotFoundHttpException`